# React.js: Managing State and Component Rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've hit a wall as I start my adventure with React.js. I've got the UI of the following time tracking app working on several levels:

http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/4n8n17tr/

What's working as hoped:

1. Filtering based on user input
2. Project clocks can be started and stopped independently

What's not working:

1. If you start one or more clocks and then try to filter, any clock that's not in the filter result set gets reset once it is re-displayed. (Just click the start on all clocks, then search for a project, then clear your search input.)

I assume this is happening because a setState is run onChange of the filter input, which is re-rendering everything and using the clock getInitialState values.

So, what's the correct way to preserve the 'state' of these clocks and the buttons when the filter re-renders the components? Should I not be storing the clock or the button 'states' as genuine React states? Do I need a function to explicitly save the clock values before the re-render?

I'm not asking for anyone to fix my code. Rather, I'm hoping for a pointer in where my understanding of React is failing.

To satisfy SO's code requirement, below is the component that contains each row in the time tracker. The clocks are started via toggleClock. IncrementClock writes the state that is getting cleared out by the search filter. Please see the complete code in the fiddle link above.

```
var LogRow = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            status: false,
            seconds: 0
        };
    },

    toggleButton: function(status) {
        this.setState({
            status: !this.state.status
        });
        this.toggleClock();
    },

    toggleClock: function() {
        var interval = '';
        if(this.state.status){
            // if clock is running, pause it.
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        } else {
            // otherwise, start it
            this.interval = setInterval(this.incrementClock, 1000);
        }
    },

    incrementClock: function() {
        this.setState({ seconds: this.state.seconds+1 });
    },

    render: function() {

        var clock = <LogClock seconds={this.state.seconds} />

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row" key={this.props.id}>
                    <div className="col-xs-7"><h4>{this.props.project.title}</h4></div>
                    <div className="col-xs-2 text-right">{clock}</div>
                    <div className="col-xs-3 text-right"><TriggerButton status={this.state.status} toggleButton={this.toggleButton} /></div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

Comment: This is how I would do it http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/4n8n17tr/8/

Its not super efficient because I had to do in a hurry.

Answer (score 3):

When you filter, you're removing `LogRow` components from the rendered output - when this happens, React unmounts the component and disposes of its state. When you subsequently change the filter and a row is once again displayed, you're getting an entirely new `LogRow` component, so `getInitialState()` is called again.

(You also have a leak here because you're not clearing the interval when these components unmount using the `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle hook - those intervals are still running away the background)

To solve this, you could move the timer state and the methods which control and increment it up out of the `LogRow` component, so its job is just to display and control the current state but not to own it.

You're currently using the `LogRow` component to tie the state and behaviour of a project timer together. You could either move this state and behaviour management up to a parent component which will manage it the same way, or out into another object, e.g.:

```
function Project(props) {
  this.id = props.id
  this.title = props.title

  this.ticking = false
  this.seconds = 0

  this._interval = null
}

Project.prototype.notifyChange = function() {
  if (this.onChange) {
    this.onChange()
  }
}

Project.prototype.tick = function() {
  this.seconds++
  this.notifyChange()
}

Project.prototype.toggleClock = function() {
  this.ticking = !this.ticking
  if (this.ticking) {
    this.startClock()
  }
  else {
    this.stopClock()
  }
  this.notifyChange()
}

Project.prototype.startClock = function() {
  if (this._interval == null) {
    this._interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000)
  }
}

Project.prototype.stopClock = function() {
  if (this._interval != null) {
    clearInterval(this._interval)
    this._interval = null
  }
}
```

Since the `clearInterval`s being used are an external source of change, you'd need to subscribe to them somehow, so I've implemented the ability to register a single `onChange` callback, which the `LogRow` component is doing when it mounts in the snippet below.

The working code snippet below does the most simple and direct thing possible to achieve this and as a result the solution has some discouraged practices (modifying props) and caveats (you can only have one "listener" on a Project) but it works. (This is generally my experience with React - it works first, then you make it "right" afterwards).

Next steps could be:

- `PROJECTS` is effectively a singleton `Store` - you could make it an object which allows registration of listeners for changes to project state. You could then add an Action object to encapsulate triggering changes to project state so `LogRow` never touches its `project` prop directly, only reads from it and calls sideways to an Action to change it. (This is just indirection, but helps with thinking about data flow). See the [Less Simple Communication](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/04-less-simple-communication.md) example in the react-trainig repo for a worked example of this.
- You could make `LogRow` completely dumb by listening for all project changes at a higher level and re-rendering everything on change. Passing individual project props to `LowRow` would then allow you to implement `shouldComponentUpdate()` so only rows which need to display a change actually re-render.

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<script src="http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.12.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="worklog" class="col-md-12">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/jsx;harmony=true">void function() { "use strict";

/* Convert seconds input to hh:mm:ss */
Number.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10);
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
    var time    = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    return time;
}

function Project(props) {
  this.id = props.id
  this.title = props.title

  this.ticking = false
  this.seconds = 0

  this._interval = null
}

Project.prototype.notifyChange = function() {
  if (typeof this.onChange == 'function') {
    this.onChange()
  }
}

Project.prototype.tick = function() {
  this.seconds++
  this.notifyChange()
}

Project.prototype.toggleClock = function() {
  this.ticking = !this.ticking
  if (this.ticking) {
    this.startClock()
  }
  else {
    this.stopClock()
  }
  this.notifyChange()
}

Project.prototype.startClock = function() {
  if (this._interval == null) {
    this._interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000)
  }
}

Project.prototype.stopClock = function() {
  if (this._interval != null) {
    clearInterval(this._interval)
    this._interval = null
  }
}

var PROJECTS = [
              new Project({id: "1", title: "Project ABC"}),
              new Project({id: "2", title: "Project XYZ"}),
              new Project({id: "3", title: "Project ACME"}),
              new Project({id: "4", title: "Project BB"}),
              new Project({id: "5", title: "Admin"})
            ];

var Worklog = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            filterText: '',
        };
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.props.projects.forEach(function(project) {
          project.stopClock()
        })
    },

    handleSearch: function(filterText) {
        this.setState({
            filterText: filterText,
        });
    },

    render: function() {

        var propsSearchBar = {
            filterText: this.state.filterText,
            onSearch: this.handleSearch
        };

        var propsLogTable = {
            filterText: this.state.filterText,
            projects: this.props.projects
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Worklog</h2>
                <SearchBar {...propsSearchBar} />
                <LogTable {...propsLogTable} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var SearchBar = React.createClass({

    handleSearch: function() {
        this.props.onSearch(
            this.refs.filterTextInput.getDOMNode().value
        );
    },

    render: function() {

        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search for a project..." value={this.props.filterText} onChange={this.handleSearch} ref="filterTextInput" />
            </div>
        );
    }

})

var LogTable = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        var rows = [];
        this.props.projects.forEach(function(project) {

            if (project.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.props.filterText.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
                return;
            }
            rows.push(<LogRow key={project.id} project={project} />);
        }, this);

        return (
            <div>{rows}</div>
        );
    }

})

var LogRow = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.props.project.onChange = this.forceUpdate.bind(this)
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.props.project.onChange = null
  },

  onToggle: function() {
    this.props.project.toggleClock()
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <div className="row" key={this.props.id}>
        <div className="col-xs-7">
          <h4>{this.props.project.title}</h4>
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-2 text-right">
          <LogClock seconds={this.props.project.seconds}/>
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-3 text-right">
          <TriggerButton status={this.props.project.ticking} toggleButton={this.onToggle}/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  }
})

var LogClock = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        return (
            <div>{this.props.seconds.toHHMMSS()}</div>
        );
    }
});

var TriggerButton = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        var button;
          button = this.props.status != false
                    ? <button className="btn btn-warning" key={this.props.id} onClick={this.props.toggleButton}><i className="fa fa-pause"></i></button>
                    : <button className="btn btn-success" key={this.props.id} onClick={this.props.toggleButton}><i className="fa fa-play"></i></button>

        return (
            <div>
                {button}
            </div>
        );

    }

})

React.render(<Worklog projects={PROJECTS} />, document.getElementById("worklog"));

}()</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for the response. Something makes me a bit weary of resolving this by using an external object. Trying to figure out what the "proper React way" of doing things is one of the biggest challenges of this framework, since documentation is fairly scarce. I certainly can't argue with your end result though. I'm going to play with your alternative suggestion of moving the behavior management up a bit, which is also how I think @dhiraj-bodicherla handled it in his comment above. I'll report back soon.

Comment: I don't think there's always a "proper React way" of doing things w.r.t. data and who owns & controls it as it's contextual - e.g. if this data's only role is display and use within this list, then any component which will be around for the entire time the list component is mounted could cromulently own the state. But if you, say, add display of this information elsewhere (e.g. a small "current project" counter in a header somewhere) that becomes a less viable solution.

Comment: This is vanilla js. It's nice but, defeats the purpose of using react and its lifecycle methods.